# Sentence Case from DB

Tags: mysql

I know UCASE converts mysql query result set to upper case, is there one for sentence case within a query?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, there's nothing native built in to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
UPDATE `tablename`
SET `fieldname` =  CONCAT(UCASE(SUBSTRING(`fieldname`,1,1)),'', 
LCASE(SUBSTRING(`fieldname`,2,LENGTH(`fieldname`))))
WHERE `id` = 1
```